# Something wrong with this for loop

Tags: php, html, loops

I have this loop which doesn't work correct and I will be very thanksful if you can show me where is the problem.. Here is:

```
$num_rows = 3;
echo '<div id="slideshow"><div>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    echo'<div class="">text</div>';
    if (($i + 1) % 1 == 0)
        echo '</div><div>';
}
echo '</div></div>';
```

The problem is that this draws one more empty div.. The result is:

```
<div><div class="">text</div></div>    
<div><div class="">text</div></div>    
<div><div class="">text</div></div>    
<div></div>
```

Why is this?
thank for your help!

Comment: why do you need the last few divs?  if(($i+1)%1==0) echo '</div><div>';    
}    
echo '</div></div>';     show your code before $num_rows=3;

Comment: What exactly is the output you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: echo '</div></div>';  this is that empty one.

Comment: before $num_rows is only the query.. This is not the full code of course, I just cutted that part which generates the empty div element.. All those divs are being rotated by JS and only one is shown in the slideshow div.. hope this helps..

Comment: that output is impossible with your code. Post the real output please...

Comment: Sorry , I corrected it - this is the output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is as below:

```
$num_rows=3;    
echo '<div id="slideshow"><div>';
for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
{
    echo'<div class="">text</div>';
    if(($i+1)%1==0) echo '</div><div>';    
}                                 ^this is the start of empty div
echo '</div></div>';    
              ^this is the end of empty div
```

After removing them your code should be like below:

```
$num_rows=3;    
echo '<div id="slideshow"><div>';
for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
{
    echo'<div class="">text</div>';
    if(($i+1)%1==0) echo '</div>';    
}    
echo '</div>';
```

As you were creating an empty div yourself. Hope this helps.

Comment: Shoaib Raza until it loops the first 3 rows that div isn't empty - it surrounds <div class="">text</div> and than it is getting an empty div.. loks like it loops 1 extra time..

Answer (score 0):

```
$num_rows = 3;
echo '<div id="slideshow"><div>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    echo'<div class="">text</div>';
    if (($i + 1) % 1 == 0)
        echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>;
```

Comment: echo '</div>'; should be last line

Comment: No, this way <div class="">text</div> is not surround by div

Comment: kya haal he tabish bhai .. :)))